# I have N Rda files where the df is named "subject". How can I load and merge them all?

Tags: r

I have hundreds of files with a unique file name in the same directory so like:

```
C:/test/alfred.Rda
C:/test/bob.Rda
C:/test/catherine.Rda
```

But when I created them I stupidly named them all "subject".. I had created them all in a loop.

So when I

```
load("C:/test/alfred.Rda")
```

alfred.Rda gets loaded as the df "subject" but when I load the next one:

```
load("C:/test/bob.Rda")
```

Unsure of how to load them all and merge into one df since every time I load one it overwrites the previous one due to having the same df name.

Ideally I would load one, rename the df to that of the file, save that as a new .Rda. Then in the end load them all and merge into one df.

Comment: If you do this again, have a look at `saveRDS` and `readRDS`. Then you can do something like: `save(object, file = 'object.rds'` and `loaded_object = readRDS('object.rds')`. However, why store the files in a set of files on disk at all. Just cram them in a list form the get go and save it in one file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach iterates non-recursively over all the files in `C:/test`, loads each file, then stores a copy of it in a single list which you can then access after the `apply` finishes.

```
# Get file names
fileNames <- list.files(path="C:/test", pattern=".Rda", recursive=FALSE)
fileNames <- trimws(substr(fileNames, 1, nchar(fileNames)-4))

# Place all files' content in a list
df_list <- list()
files <- list.files(path="C:/test", pattern="*.Rda", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)
mergedList <- lapply(files, function(x) {
    load(x)                # bring the 'df' variable back to life
    df_list[[x]] <- df     # store a copy of 'df' in a list using the filename
})

# Place into a single df for further analysis
names(mergedList) <- fileNames
dfFinal <- do.call(rbind, mergedList)
```

Comment: I would have named them with the file names, but if you taken this approach, I'd now add an additional line at the end to make the "subjects" unique: `names(df_list) <- paste0("subject", 1:length(df_list) )` or perhaps `names(df_list) <-  gsub("C:/test/|\\.Rda", "", files) )`

Comment: Then use `do.call(rbind, df_list)` and perhaps label the lines with the appropriate names.

Comment: Oh this is super unexpected.. when I use Tim's chunk I get
`[[1]]
function (x, df1, df2, ncp, log = FALSE) 
{
    if (missing(ncp)) 
        .Call(C_df, x, df1, df2, log)
    else .Call(C_dnf, x, df1, df2, ncp, log)
}
<bytecode: 0xe3c6fa8>
<environment: namespace:stats>`

Comment: What does `files` contain?  What does `class(files)` show you?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen nevermind. I figured it out. `df_list[[x]] <- df ` was causing my error.. instead of `df` I should have updated it to `subject`. It works like a charm! Thank you so much!!